# Offset function doesn't refresh in excel

Tags: excel, formula, offset, valueerror

I use an excel file, where i collect data from 5 excel files. I use offset function to simplify my job. I fill these 5 files each day, then I save and close. When I open the collecting file, I got #VALUE error. When I check the function with the function button I can see the result in the formula board.

```
=OFFSET('Y:\[path]\[sourcenapi.xlsm]POD új'!$CL$219,0,RAW(2:2)-1)
```

When I open the source files, I get the correct numbers in my collecting file, so the formula is right. In setting the formulas are calculated automatically.
What can I do to refresh the files without opening the sourcefiles?

Comment: `OFFSET` will not work with a closed source file. You could use `INDEX` instead: `=INDEX('Y:\[path]\[sourcenapi.xlsm]POD új'!$219:$219,1,90+ROW(2:2)-1)`

Comment: thnaks, it works!